# Can I refer to a specific Cognito User Pool as a principal in an AWS IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I want to restrict access to an AWS S3 bucket so that new objects can only be created by users who have authenticated through a specific Cognito User Pool. Looking through the AWS documentation I can't work out how to specify the user pool as a principal in the policy. Can anyone help me with this?

If this isn't possible then I'd appreciate some pointers/guidance which might help me achieve the desired result using some other technique. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a User Pool will not allow you to do this, seen as you only get an access token for an authenticated entity. You'll probably need to create an identity pool, which allows users in your user pool to retrieve temporary IAM credentials. In the identity pool, you can also configure the role these logged in users get with their temporary credentials. You can use these roles to restrict access to the S3 bucket to only those authenticated users.

In the example below, you can see the settings of an identity pool configured with a Cognito user pool as authentication provider. It will either use the default roles configured on top (big red rectangle) or you can choose a custom role for the Cognito authentication provider (small rectangle). All roles can be managed using IAM.
[image: IdentityPoolSettings screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I do have an identity pool which contains the user pool and so this sounds like the right approach. Are you able to provide an example which might get me started please?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the screenshot of an identity pool which shows where to configure the roles for (un)authenticated users. If you only use a single authentication provider and only allow authenticated users, you'll only have to deal with the authenticated role (which you can find in IAM).